# I can't find a way to extract data from single quoted JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm currently working on a little project of mine in Python and have to work with JSON responses from APIs, but I can't find a way to extract a single field form the data sent by the API :

My code is as follows :

```py
def netdisc():
    print('Trying auto discovery of the HUE Bridge')
    with curl.get('https://discovery.meethue.com/') as r:
        if r.status_code == 200:
            req = r.json()
    ip = json.load(req)[u'internalipaddress']
    print(ip)
```

*NOTE : curl is the name I always give to the `requests` module*

And the API response is :

```json
[{'id': 'REDACTED', 'internalipaddress': 'REDACTED'}]
```

And I need to extract the value of the field `internalipaddress`

The issue here, is that the Philips HUE discovery service output only single quoted JSON and as far as my knowledge go the json module can only process double quoted json

```py
>>> json.loads("{'id': 'REDACTED', 'internalipaddress': 'REDACTED'}")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

If I change every single quote for a double quote, it works just fine :

```py
>>> json.loads('{"id": "REDACTED", "internalipaddress": "REDACTED"}')[u'internalipaddress']
'REDACTED'
```

If someone had an idea/solution that would be awsome

Comment: `req = r.json()` -> `req` is already JSON object, no need to load second time. `requests.Response.json()` is convenient function.

Comment: I believe it's needed as

Comment: no, it is not needed, [look at the docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)

Comment: @NicolasFormichella `ip = r.json()[0]['internalipaddress']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand: `req = r.json()`. This has already decoded the `json` response for you and converted it to a python `dict`.

Did you mean: `print(req['internalipaddress'])`?

Just to be clear about the types involved:

```py
import json

j = '{"id": "REDACTED", "internalipaddress": "REDACTED"}'

print(type(j), j)

d = json.loads(j)

print(type(d), d)
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'> {"id": "REDACTED", "internalipaddress": "REDACTED"}
<class 'dict'> {'id': 'REDACTED', 'internalipaddress': 'REDACTED'}
```

The variable `j` is a string whose contents match the [json](https://www.json.org) specification which means that the `json` module can be used to convert the string into a python `dict`.

When each are printed, the string has to have double quotes around strings, but when python prints the contents of the `dict` the strings there are rendered as being surrounded with single quotes.

Comment: [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) strings use ONLY double quotes.

Comment: @MetallimaX, `requests.Response.json()` already converted the JSON string to `dict`. [Look at the docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)